# MVC5 DataAnnotations - Accept Specific Numbers

Tags: asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

How can I set a ViewModel to accept only specific values with a data annotation?
For example, I only want the input values from a form to be 2 or 4.
I'm looking for something like `[Range(2, 4)]`, but that still accepts numbers in between.  I want to list the specific numbers to accept.

```
[Required]
public int NumberParticipants { get; set; }
```

Also looking for the same thing with strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[RegularExpression("^(2|4)$", ErrorMessage = "Please enter 2 or 4")]
```

Comment: Thanks I really have to learn these.
What about with string values, is that something like this?
`[RegularExpression("^("I"|"T")$"]]`

Comment: like this [RegularExpression("^(I|T)$")]

Comment: So no quotes.  Thanks